# commons-collections jar missing in hibernate 5.2.5

Tags: hibernate

I am newbie at learning hibernate framework.

I have downloaded hibernate package 5.2.5 and I was going through tutorial to begin with from here : https://kaanmutlu.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/hibernate-installationsetup-on-eclipse-ide/
But the **common-collections jar** is missing from package.

There are other sites where I can download common-collections jar but I don't know the version needed for hibernate 5.2.5.

So does hibernate no longer needs common-collections OR if needed from where can I download **common-collections jar**?

Comment: Maven would sort this out for you.  Give it a try.  I'd be wary of a 2011 tutorial.  That's dated, don't you think?

Comment: I have found common-collections.jar 3.2 from this  [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2). Is this correct version to be used with hibernate 5.2.5? @duffymo

Answer (score 0):

Download and include all libraries in your project.

Or learn how maven works. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven